# Embed vimeo video into tinyMCE editor

Tags: tinymce, embed, vimeo

I know nothing about programming so apologies if I get terminologies wrong.

I need to embed a video from vimeo into tinyMCE editor. This is the embed code that Vimeo provides for its videos:

```
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/24676022" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

When I paste that into the editor and click update, nothing happens. Does it just hate it and won't let me do it or is there a simple workaround?

Comment: what version of tinymce did you use? what is your tinymce config? did you test it using the tinymce demo page (http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php)?

Comment: I'm also having this same problem

Answer (score 1):

Are you pasting that HTML code into the HTML version of your tinyMCE editor?

You cannot simply copy and paste HTML into the editor's WYSIWYG editor.

Unless you are doing any post-processing of the HTML you are trying to save, the iframe should be saved (and shown in the final version) as well.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simply to configure TinyMCE to accept the iframe tag as a valid element.
You can learn more here: http://www.frederikvig.com/2010/10/how-to-add-support-for-iframes-and-other-elements-to-tinymce-in-episerver-cms/

Answer (score 0):

you can use `htmlspecialchars_decode($data_from_mysql)`

it will display the video in your web browser....

well this works perfect for me..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following jquery code to embedd iframes into your tinymce created pages:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $obj = $('.mce-object-iframe');
    var video_url = $obj.attr('data-mce-p-src');
    var width = $obj.attr('width');
    var height = $obj.attr('height');

    $obj.replaceWith('<iframe width="'+width+'" height="'+height+'" src="'+video_url+'" style="border:0px;"></iframe>');
});
```